# Designer Workflow logic that would trigger on multiple conditions selected

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that is published to a Form Library shown below:

[image]

In addition, I created an Approval Workflow that would fire once the form has been filled out. When the Submit button is pressed after the desired selection has been made, the Form Library gets updated based on what the user selected shown below:

[image]

The condition that I'm trying to satisfy is, "*If Blue and Yellow is selected then notify the Color Approver Group*". The issue is I can't seem to get the logic in the Workflow right to get the desired results. I have looked for articles but nothing close to what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create 3 separate check boxes. One for each color. Then get those values on your workflow condition. I'm guessing that you are using multiple selection?